# Can I increase the efficiency of this OptaPlanner Drools file?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I've been trying to create a Drools file for timetabling, but OptaPlanner takes a long while to run even though the number of entities is quite small (less than 400).

The default Late Acceptance strategy reduces the hard constraint very quickly while leaving the soft constraint high, but hits a performance wall before reaching feasibility. Tabu Search reduces both scores but does so more slowly than Late Acceptance, and also hits the wall before feasibility, earlier than Late Acceptance does.

I wonder if some of the exponential or group evaluators are written wrongly or inefficiently? I've had some trouble with forall giving awkward syntax errors, claiming that ObjectTypes can't be matched.

```
import data.Module
import data.Session
import data.Slot
import data.Program
import data.Staffer
import data.SessionAlternativeGroup
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScoreHolder
import enums.SessionType

import java.util.Collections

import data.Constants

global HardSoftScoreHolder scoreHolder;

// Check for one tutor overused in the same slot
rule "staffClash"
    when
        $s1 : Session($tutors : tutors, $id : ID)
        $tutor : Staffer() from $tutors
        accumulate($s2 : Session($s2.overlaps($s1)); $tuse1 : sum($s2.getTutorWeeks($tutor)))
        eval($tuse1 > 12)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);
end

// Room used for one module cannot be used for others at the same time
// (But it could be used for the same type of session on the same module)
rule "moduleRoomClash"
    when
        $s1 : Session($mod : module, $typ : type, $room : room, $id : ID)
        $s2 : Session(module != $mod, type != $typ, room == $room, $s2.overlaps($s1))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);
end

// Apply badness of time slots
rule "timeBadness"
    when
        Session($slots : allSlots, $count : students)
        Slot ($bad : badness) from $slots
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,0-($bad * $count));
end

// Apply staff dislike of time slots
rule "staffDislikedTime"
    when
        $s : Session($staff : tutors, $slots : allSlots, $count : students)
        $st : Staffer($slot : dislikeSlots) from $staff
        eval($slots.contains($slot))
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,0-
          (Constants.BADNESS_STAFFER_DISLIKES_SLOT) * $count * ($s.getTutorWeeks($st)));
end

// Non computer sessions can be in computer rooms, but it's better not to
rule "unnecessaryComputerRoom"
    when
        $s : Session(!needsComputer, room!.isComputer, $count : students)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,0-
          (Constants.BADNESS_UNNECESSARY_COMPUTER_ROOM) * $count);
end


// COMPULSORY, MANDATORY sessions must not clash with ANY other mandatory session on that
// program (if they did, it would be impossible to take that module)
rule "CompulsoryMandatoryClash"
    when
        Program( $comp : compulsories, $all : all )
        $s1 : Session( module memberOf $comp, $ID : ID, mandatory == true )
        Session( module memberOf $all, ID > $ID, mandatory == true, overlaps($s1) )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);
end

// COMPULSORY, MANDATORY sessions must have at least ONE session in each altgroup on that
// programme that they do not clash with
rule "ProgrammeCompulsoryPracticalWipeout"
    when
        Program( $comp : compulsories, $all : all )
        $s1 : Session(module memberOf $comp, $ID : ID, mandatory)
        SessionAlternativeGroup(module memberOf $all, $sessions : sessions)
        forall ($s2 : Session(overlaps($s1)) from $sessions)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);
end

// It's bad for elective modules on a programme to clash.
rule "ProgrammeElectiveLectureClash"
    when
        Program( $el : electives )
        $s1 : Session( module memberOf $el, $ID : ID, mandatory == true )
        Session( module memberOf $el, ID > $ID, mandatory == true, overlaps($s1) )
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,0-Constants.BADNESS_ELECTIVE_CLASH);
end

// Lectures should be earlier in the week than practicals
rule "LecturesBeforePracticals"
    when
        Session ($module : module, isLecture, $lecslot : slot)
        Session (module == $module, !isLecture, (slot!.ordinal) < ($lecslot!.ordinal))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);
end

// Mandatory sessions shouldn't overlap any sessions on the same module
// (practicals CAN overlap each other, and normally would)
rule "PracticalOverLecture"
    when
        $s1 : Session ($mod : module, $ID : ID, mandatory)
        $s2 : Session (module == $mod, ID > $ID, $s1.overlaps($s2))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);
end

// Elective sessions of different types on the same module
// shouldn't completely overlap each other
rule "MultipleTypesOverlap"
    when
        $s1 : Session ($mod : module, $ID : ID, $type : type, !mandatory)
        $ag : SessionAlternativeGroup($mod == module, type == $type, $s2s : sessions)
        forall ($s2 : Session(overlaps($s1)) from $s2s);
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);
end



// Sessions on a module should be as close as possible to each other
rule "PracticalsNearLectures"
    when
        $lec : Session (lastSlot != null, $mod : module, $ID : ID)
        $prac : Session (slot != null, module == $mod, $count : students, ID > $ID)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,
               $count * (Math.min(0,0-($prac.getSlot().ordinal - ($lec.getLastSlot().ordinal+1)))));
end

// 12pm or 1pm slot should be free for staff for lunch
rule "NoLunchForYouStaffer"
       when
           Session($tutors : tutors, $day : slot.day, containsDayOrdinal(4))
           $tutor : Staffer() from $tutors
           Session(tutors contains $tutor, slot.day == $day, containsDayOrdinal(5))
       then
           scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);
end

// 12pm or 1pm slot should be free for students, for lunch
rule "NoLunchForYouStudent"
   when
       Program ($comp : compulsories)
       Session($day : slot.day, $comp contains module, containsDayOrdinal(4))
       Session(slot.day == $day, $comp contains module, containsDayOrdinal(5))
   then
       scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);
end

// Number of days staff members are in should be fairly distributed
rule "StaffInDaysFairness"
     when
         $s : Staffer(isAL == false)
         accumulate(Session(tutors contains $s, $day : slot!.day); $days1 : count($day))
     then
         scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,(int)-(($days1 ^ 2)));
end

// Staff should have a clear day
rule "StaffClearDay"
     when
         $s : Staffer(isAL == false)
         accumulate(Session(tutors contains $s, $day : slot!.day != 2); $days1 : count($day))
         eval(($days1 > 3))
     then
         scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,-1);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INFO` logging outputs the score calculation speed. The benchmarker (even better) even shows it in a graph. Higher is better.

Do a 40 second run, comment portions of the rules and watch that score calculation speed to find the bottleneck rules.

Comment: Thanks. It was more questions about how to speed up the existing rules, though. For example the ProgrammeCompulsoryPracticalWipeout rule seems to have to do 4 nested loops (programmes, s1 sessions, altgroups, matching sessions) and I wonder if there are any suggestions for expressing this more efficiently in Drools.

Comment: ... and sure enough commenting out ProgrammeCompulsoryPracticalWipeout speeds up the calculation more than tenfold.

Comment: Having run the benchmarker, the soft score drops, jumps around at random for a while, then levels off.. unfortunately it levels off at -350,000 when there are still obvious human avoidable errors in the schedule :(

Comment: It seems to be getting the hard constraint right down, then trying to improve soft properties of the schedule, but unable to do so without creating a clash (which would lower the hard score) and unable to take enough steps to pursue that route to rectify the clash, so it dies on that hill :(